# making function is number is odd or even

Tags: function, functional-programming

I want to make a function to find a number is odd or even by using only increment or decrement function . no another operator like equal or modular operator

Comment: what's the programming language ?!!

Comment: Use a loop, subtract by 2, and see if you end up with 0 or 1.  Or try recursion to do the same thing.

Comment: Just decrement/increment twice each time and recurse until you end up with 1 or 0.

Comment: This is a very vague question, it would be up to the language. Maybe with a little bit broader explanation you could find help.

Answer (score 1):

```
def isOdd(n:Int) = {
    if(n <= 1) n;
    else isOdd(n - 2);
}
```

this will return 1 or 0 (true or false) whether or not the number n is odd.
I forgot to mention that this code is runnable in Scala.

It's tail-recursive, too.

Comment: Can u explain  first line of it

Comment: Definition of a function named isOdd with the n typed as integer. The return type is determined by the implicit return value.
Basically I imply the basic assumptions of Scala.

Answer (score 0):

check something like this with % mod operator

```
using System;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
    for (int i = 0; i <= 100; i++)
    {
        if (IsOdd(i))
        {
        Console.WriteLine(i);
        }
    }
    }

    public static bool IsOdd(int value)
    {
    return value % 2 != 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: M.qassas i want function that don't use modular

Answer (score 0):

perhaps

```
public bool isEven(int number){
    return number/2.0 == Convert.ToInt32(number/2.0)
}
```

I'm not quite sure how you intend to test a number for being even without an equals or mod operator.

Lucas

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this? This solution however does use assignment and logical operators.

```
var isEven = true;
function makeDivayanshusHomework (number) {
    if (number < 0) {
        for(i = 0; i < 2*number; i++) {
            number++;
        }
    }

    while (number > 0) {
        number--;
        isEven = isEven ? false : true;
    }

    return isEven;
}
```

edit: as per sascha10000's comments, the solution below is perhaps even somewhat more functional:

```
function makeDivayanshusHomework (number) {
    if (Math.sqrt(number*number) > 1) {
        return makeDivayanshusHomework(number-2)
    }
    else {
        return Math.sqrt(number*number); // 1 when odd, 0 otherwise
    }
}
```

which brings me almost to sascha10000's original answer, although this method gracefully handles negative integers. Did your teacher specify to what extent the input has to be sanitised?

Comment: Haha awesome function name. I know this is not a senseful comment. But it was too funny for not commenting it. But this is not functional. You are mutating variables which is not allowed.

Comment: It is still not functional, because ++ -- are postfix decrements/increments which resolves to number = number + 1 or number = number + 1 => still mutating the variables. Thus it's not functional you would need to use constants instead of variables. Therefore you would use recursion for your approach.